# SVN won't update from command line tool

Tags: svn, svn-update

I am trying to update my repo, using `svn update` command line tool.

But it won't download newly added or missing files.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by newly added? Newly added to the repository or newly added to your working copy?

Comment: Maybe the files were added to a different branch than the one of your working copy.

Comment: I'm having trouble with my compiler, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Read [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)!

Why do you assume that you [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) a repository?

> **`svn update`** brings changes from the repository into your working copy.

So you update your [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy), not a [repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository).

**Working copy?**

Working copy is a local checkout of a specific repository location (e.g. branch, trunk, whatever). So even if you know that other developers committed to the repository it could be that they committed to another location. You can always issues ['svn log'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) command to check what's new in a repository.

> A working copy is, quite literally, a local copy of a particular
>   version of a user's VCS-managed data upon which that user is free to
>   work. Working copies appear to other software just as any other
>   local directory full of files, so those programs don't have to be
>   “version-control-aware” in order to read from and write to that data.
>   The task of managing the working copy and communicating changes made
>   to its contents to and from the repository falls squarely to the
>   version control system's client software.

**Repository?**

Repository is the place where all versioned data and history is kept safe.

> At the core of the version control system is a repository, which is
>   the central store of that system's data.